# Explorer.exe svchost ntdll threads hang, lags Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, cpu-usage, lag, svchost

My windows 10 / explorer lags tremendously at certain intervals, to the point that music playing and mouse cursor stutter heavily. The problem always comes back after a while after restart.

Using ProcessHacker I was able to track it down to svchost, ntdll.dll, hanging on ntdll.dll!RtlAcquireSRWLockShared. The service MpsSvc seems to be windows firewall. This is the stack:

[image]

I can't see anything familiar in the stack, and am a general newb when it comes to debugging windows procedures. Can anyone make any sense of this?

The last two responses [on this microsoft thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/high-cpu-usage-by-exploreexe-for-a-minute-after/72a0fcfa-bf74-4fee-88f3-efeb1683f230) sound a lot like my problem. But naturally there is no answer there despite one being appointed.

- how can I tell what it's querying from the disk?
- how can I tell if/what it's parsing from the registry?
- how can I get a more detailed stack?
- how can I just make the hanging stop? :)

---

### [EDIT]

Windows Performance Analyzer is awesome, can't believe I didn't know about it. Thanks @magicandre1981

Comment: open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command: **wpr.exe -start CPU && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl** after you captured the CPU usage/hang for around 60s, go back to cmd and press a key to stop logging.

Comment: ok, post your finding as answer. Load the debug symbols to get proper function name resolving: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/symbol-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the firewall was doing a TON of calls to the remote procededure call runtime:

[image]

It probably started due to a recent update to my VPN. It was getting in some kind of loop for blocking both my network connection and my virtual vpn network connection at the same time. I [disabled the firewall](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/q-how-can-i-disable-or-enable-windows-firewall-specific-network-connection) for the vpn tunnel.

Not sure specifically what was going on, but this fixed it.

### [EDIT]

I still sometimes get slowdown or stutter for a short time. For Explorer.exe I get 1x `SHCore.dll!DllGetClassObject+0x680` thread and a handful of `ntdll.dll "RtlAcquireSRWLockShared+0x3b90`ones using cpu. And this tested with firewall 100% off.

It's not as bad but I have to dig deeper.

### [EDIT2]

I think it's still my vpn software. I see openvpn using 12-16% cpu sometimes and it FOR SOME REASON interrupts or otherwise lags explorer.exe.

I should maybe take that question on the vpn provider's forums. Will post any updates here.